# Cypher query issue

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to find the relationship, `r`, between two nodes, `n`, and `m`, and delete the relationship.  Here is what I've tried:

```
 START n=node:uid(uid = 'f9c81808-976d-4d38-8038-76bb55463b3e')
 WHERE HAS (m.uid) AND m.uid='84cfdbd1-33f1-44d5-9692-9b0663887973'
 MATCH (n)-[r:attachedTo]-(m)
 DELETE r
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

I get the following error: `expected return clause`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't clearly understand why you did this;

```
    n=node:uid(uid = 'f9c81808-976d-4d38-8038-76bb55463b3e')
```

but I think following query sample might help you a little bit.

```
    START n=node(*), m=node(*)
    match (n)-[r]->(m)
    where has(n.name) and has(m.name) and n.name='Running' and m.name = 'Photo'
    delete r
```

Comment: If he has indexed the uid property, it doesn't make sense to get all nodes (twice) and test for property value

Answer (score 2):

The correct query is:

```
START n=node:uid(uid = 'f9c81808-976d-4d38-8038-76bb55463b3e')
MATCH (n)-[r:attachedTo]-(m)
WHERE HAS (m.uid) AND m.uid='84cfdbd1-33f1-44d5-9692-9b0663887973'
DELETE r
```

since the WHERE clause comes after the MATCH clause, look at the [documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-delete.html).

Answer (score 1):

Since you seem to have indexed your nodes on `uid`, you should get both nodes from that index, and then match the relationship between them

```
START n=node:uid(uid='f9c81808-976d-4d38-8038-76bb55463b3e'), m=node:uid(uid='84cfdbd1-33f1-44d5-9692-9b0663887973')
MATCH n-[r:attachedTo]-m
DELETE r
```

Comment: So this is less computation than Zafer's answer

Comment: Yes, unless you indexed every property of every node, or have two nodes in your database, it is very likely to be much more efficient. The whole point of indexing something is to avoid having to look at each datum in the database in order to test it for an attribute. But don't take my word for it, run both queries in the console with `PROFILE ` prefixed and look at the execution plan (particularly `_db_hits=?`).

Comment: I appreciate your answer.